# javascript: durandaljs, applyBindings inside a viewmodel

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, durandal

I'm trying to make a single page application with dynamic content, using durandaljs. For example, if you change the language in your settings, then the UI gets updated. I'm using SignalR to load the objects from the server, and everything works fine apart from when I navigate. The first time I load the view, I'm getting the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Unable to parse bindings.
Message: ReferenceError: router is not defined;
Bindings value: compose: { 
        model: router.activeItem, //wiring the router
        afterCompose: router.afterCompose, //wiring the router
        transition:'entrance', //use the 'entrance' transition when switching views
        cacheViews:true //telling composition to keep views in the dom, and reuse them (only a good idea with singleton view models)
        }
```

but if I reload the page, then the view is displayed correctly.
Here is an example of the viewmodel:

```
define(function (require) {
    var p = require('hubs/myhub'),
        rep = require('repositories/myrepository');
    var myViewModel = function(data, proxy, cookie) {
        var self = this;
        self.proxy = proxy;
        self.cookie = cookie;
        self.Labels = ko.observableArray([]);
        try {
            self.proxy
                .invoke('Setup', self.cookie.Username, self.cookie.Language)
                .done(function (res) {
                    if (res.Result) {
                        console.log(JSON.stringify(res.Object, null, 4));
                        self.Labels(res.Object.Labels);
                    } else {
                        console.log(res.Error);
                    }
                });
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e.message);
        }
    };
    return {
        activate: function () {
            var cookie = JSON.parse($.cookie(rep.cookieName));
            ko.applyBindings(myViewModel({}, p.proxy, cookie), document.getElementById('my_container'));
        }
    };
});
```

If I take off the applyBinding of the activate function, then there is no more issue within the navigation. Would there be proper way to do this?

I've modified the return statement for:

```
return {
        myModel: new myViewModel ({ }, p.proxy, JSON.parse($.cookie(rep.cookieName))),
        activate: function () {
            this.myModel.init();
        }
    };
```

and wrapped the signalr call inside an init() function. everything works great now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is exactly the right way! DUrandal calls the Ko.applybindings for YOU ;) Meaning Durandal does the binding!

[Hot Towel SPA Durandal Knockout and Dynatree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15412386/hot-towel-spa-durandal-knockout-and-dynatree)